# Parse cloud code: simple function not working

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, cloud

I'm trying to implement a `beforeSave` function on cloud code and the following simple function doesn't work when there are multiple hashtags. Given if `Product` has two hashtags and the `Hashtag` table is empty, the following parse cloud code stores the second hashtag twice with a `count` of 1:

```js
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Product", function(req, res) {
  var product = req.object;
  var hashtags = product.get("hashtags");
  for (var i = 0; i < hashtags.length; i++) {
    var currentHashtag = hashtags[i].toLowerCase();
    var hashtagQuery = new Parse.Query("Hashtag")
    hashtagQuery.equalTo("label", currentHashtag);
    hashtagQuery.find({
      success: function(results) {
        if (results.length == 0) {
          var hashtagClass = Parse.Object.extend("Hashtag");
          var newHashtag = new hashtagClass();
          newHashtag.set("label", currentHashtag);
          newHashtag.set("count", 1);
          newHashtag.save();
        } else {
          var hashtagObj = results[0];
          hashtagObj.increment("count");
          hashtagObj.save();
        }
        if (i == hashtags.length - 1)
          res.sucesss();
      },
      error: function() {
        res.error("Oops");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line var hashtagObj = results[0]; to this line

```
var hashtagObj = results[i];
```